# How to set Visible false and true RadEditor using Javascript ?

Tags: asp.net

How to set Visible false and true RadEditor using Javascript ?  Please Help me . Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [set_visible](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-setvisible.html) function like so:

```
var editor = $find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");
editor.set_visible(true);
```

Here is a link to the RadEditor client side documentation: [Getting familiar with Client-Side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html)

Hope this helps.

I notice you are a new user, If this or any other questions you ask on the site provide the answers you are looking for, remember to accept the answers (It rewards posters who give correct answers, gives you reputation points and lets other users find correct answers easily).

See the following for more information: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235)